# SQL Server: Temporary timeout on procedures, views and functions

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, view, timeout

In our database we have different functions, procedures and views, that throw timeout exceptions in our application. Even in SSMS the scripts are very slow. The problem only occurs early in the morning, between 7AM and 9AM, especially on monday morning. Some of these scripts are very short and in the afternoon the duration is below one second.

The sessions that run slow are not blocked by any other session. There are some scheduled agent jobs running during this time, but these are also running in the afternoon. Since views are also affected, it can not be parameter sniffing, nor any other problem with query plans. We've no idea, what causes these fluctuations.

One of the affected views looks like this:

```
create view [dbo].[View01]
as
select
 A.Id                                                                                                               as Id
,A.Client_Id                                                                                                        as Client_Id
,A.Status                                                                                                           as Status
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table01] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable01
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table02] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable02
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table03] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable03
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table04] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable04
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table05] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable05
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table06] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable06
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table07] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable07
,(select count(Id) from [dbo].[Table08] where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable08
from [dbo].[Address] as A;
```

The default duration of a query on this view is about 0.2 seconds.

**Edit:**

Whe have the following indexes set on the tables:

```
Table01     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Status) include (Adress_Id)
Table02     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Status) include (Adress_Id)
Table03     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Status) include (Adress_Id)
Table04     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Adress_Id)
Table05     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Status) include (Adress_Id)
Table06     no index
Table07     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Status) include (Adress_Id)
Table08     nonclustered index on (Client_Id, Adress_Id)
```

Comment: What is in the server log file at this time?

Comment: Transaction log backup information only. There are neither errors, nor warnings.

Comment: how many rows do you retrieve from that view each query? do tables 01-08 all have indexes on Client_Id, Adress_Id and Status?

Comment: @TZHX We retrieve 47538 rows. I added the indexes to the question.

Comment: this probably wont help with performance, but i would write your subquery more like this ,(select count(1) from [dbo].[Table01] T1 where T1.Client_Id = A.Client_Id and T1.Adress_Id = A.Id and T1.Status = A.Status)

Answer (score 0):

This could properbly be due to locking. Try to add table hint: "with (nolock)" to your queries if it´s ok to do dirty reads. Eg:

```
create view [dbo].[View01]
as
select
 A.Id                                                                                                               as Id
,A.Client_Id                                                                                                        as Client_Id
,A.Status                                                                                                           as Status
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table01] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable01
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table02] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable02
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table03] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable03
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table04] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable04
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table05] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable05
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table06] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable06
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table07] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable07
,(select count(PK) from [dbo].[Table08] with (nolock) where Client_Id = A.Client_Id and Adress_Id = A.Id and Status = A.Status)   as CountTable08
from [dbo].[Address] as A with (nolock);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We already tried this, however this change had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` in the period of "slowlyness" to see which session is waiting for what.

Once you find out your waitings you can consult what they mean here: [SQL Server Wait Types Library](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/).

Please update your question with the results from this DMV so we'll be able to find the cause.